# response.redirect page from asp classic to mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I have an ASP classic application running and in same folder i have moved the mvc web deploy package.
Now when i redirect my page from classic asp to a controller/action it shows error 404.
It is running fine on local IIS but not on web server
Please help

Comment: Please show the code where you are doing the redirect. If you type the url you are redirecting to in the address bar, does it work?

Comment: if ulev=5 then Response.redirect("Home/Index?vlop="&Session("uno"))

Comment: that is how i am redirecting to mvc controller. This works fine on my localhost IIS but when i upload it on server it passes the address in address bar but gives error

Comment: in code i am calling the action of controller with a querystring value

Comment: Please [edit] and add the above information to your question.